# Java Background

Tags: java, processing

I'm new to Java and neither me nor my partner can seem to figure out how to set the background for a specific section. We need to have the background for the Jamaican flag set to (250, 230, 82) but only for that part. Currently, when we run the program on Processing 2.0, the line messes the entire flow of what we've written. This is what we have so far:

```
int x=0;
void setup() {
  size(320, 270);
  background(0);
  noStroke();
  frameRate(240);
}
void draw() {
  //germany, flag 1
  fill(0); //black first horizontal bar
  rect(0+x, 0, width+x, width); 
  fill(255, 0, 0); //red middle horizontal bar
  rect(0+x, 90, width+x, width);
  fill(240, 240, 0); //gold last horizontal bar
  rect(0+x, 180, width+x, width);

  //japan, flag 2
  fill(255); //white background
  rect(0+x-width, 0, width, height);
  fill(255, 0, 0); //red circle middle
  ellipse(width/2+x-width, height/2, 150, 150);

  //france, flag 3
  fill(0, 0, 255); //left blue vertical bar
  rect(0+x-2*width, 0, width/3, height);
  fill(255); //middle white vertical bar
  rect(width/3+x-2*width, 0, width/3, height);
  fill(255, 0, 0); //right red vertical bar
  rect(2.0/3.0*width+x-2*width, 0, width/3, height);

  //brazil, flag 4
  fill(0, 180, 0); //dark green background
  rect(0+x-3*width, 0, width, height);
  fill(230, 230, 0); //gold rhombus
  triangle(width/10+x-3*width, height/2, width/2+x-3*width, 30, width/2+x-3*width, 240);        //gold rhombus left side
  triangle(9.0/10.0*width+x-3*width, height/2, width/2+x-3*width, 30, width/2+x-3*width, 240); //gold rhombus right side
  fill(0, 0, 150); //dark blue circle
  ellipse(width/2+x-3*width, height/2, 120, 120);
  fill(255); //stars
  ellipse(170+x-3*width, 170, 3, 3); //stars 1
  ellipse(177+x-3*width, 185, 3, 3); //stars 2
  ellipse(151+x-3*width, 155, 3, 3); //stars 3
  ellipse(112+x-3*width, 145, 3, 3); //stars 4
  ellipse(132+x-3*width, 165, 3, 3); //stars 5
  ellipse(147+x-3*width, 148, 3, 3); //stars 6
  ellipse(157+x-3*width, 168, 3, 3); //stars 7
  ellipse(180+x-3*width, 188, 3, 3); //stars 8
  ellipse(190+x-3*width, 158, 3, 3); //stars 9

  //sweden, flag 5
  fill(0, 100, 190); //blueish teal background
  rect(0+x-4*width, 0, width, height); //the "-4*width" needs to be added after every
  fill(240, 210, 0); // gold nordic cross //^first x-place in order for the flags to follow one after
  rect(width/4+x-4*width, 0, 30, height); //another like a big continuous flag, so the subsequent 
  rect(0+x-4*width, height/2-15, width, 30); //ones will be "-5*width", "-6*width", etc
  //the "-15"^ is to center the horizontal line

  //norsefire, flag 6
  fill(0); //black background
  rect(0+x-5*width, 0, width, height);
  fill(255, 0, 0); //red double cross thing
  rect(0+x-5*width, height/2-15, width, 30);//horizontal line
  rect(width/8+x-5*width, 0, 30, height);//vertical line 1
  rect(3.0/8.0*width+x-5*width, 0, 30, height);//vertical line 2

  //chile, flag 7
  fill(0, 0, 250); //blue left horizontal bar
  rect(0+x-6*width, 0, 125, 145); 
  fill(250); //white right horizontal bar
  rect(125+x-6*width, 0, 320, 145);
  fill(250, 0, 0); //red last horizontal bar
  rect(0+x-6*width, 145, 320, 270);
  line(42+x-6*width, 53, 63, 30);
  line(82+x-6*width, 53, 63, 30);
  line(82+x-6*width, 53, 105, 58);
  line(15+x-6*width, 58, 42, 53);
  line(90+x-6*width, 75, 105, 58);
  line(35+x-6*width, 75, 15, 58);
  line(35+x-6*width, 75, 25, 95);
  line(25+x-6*width, 95, 53, 88);
  line(53+x-6*width, 88, 95, 95);
  line(95+x-6*width, 95, 90, 75); 

  //jamaica, flag 8
  //  background(250, 230, 82); // This line is messing everything up
  fill (0, 250, 0); //green triangle top
  triangle (10+x-7*width, 0, 160+x-7*width, 120, 310+x-7*width, 0);
  fill (0, 250, 0); //green triangle bot
  triangle (10+x-7*width, 270, 160+x-7*width, 150, 310+x-7*width, 270);
  fill (0); //black triangle left
  triangle (0+x-7*width, 10, 145+x-7*width, 135, 0+x-7*width, 260);
  fill (0); //black triangle right
  triangle (320+x-7*width, 10, 175+x-7*width, 135, 320+x-7*width, 260);

  //puerto rico, flag 9 
  fill(0, 0, 250); //blue triangle
  triangle(0+x-8*width, 0, 0+x-8*width, 270, 166+x-8*width, 135);
  fill(255, 0, 0); //red quad 1
  quad(0+x-8*width, 0, 54+x-8*width, 54, 320+x-8*width, 54, 320+x-8*width, 0);
  fill(250); //white quad 1
  quad(54+x-8*width, 54, 108+x-8*width, 108, 320+x-8*width, 108, 320+x-8*width, 54);
  fill(255, 0, 0); //red quad 2
  quad(108+x-8*width, 108, 135+x-8*width, 135, 320+x-8*width, 135, 320+x-8*width, 108);
  fill(255, 0, 0); //red quad 3
  quad(135+x-8*width, 135, 108+x-8*width, 162, 320+x-8*width, 162, 320+x-8*width, 135);
  fill(250); //white quad 2
  quad(108+x-8*width, 162, 320+x-8*width, 162, 320+x-8*width, 216, 54+x-8*width, 216);
  fill(250, 0, 0); //red quad 4
  quad(54+x-8*width, 216, 0+x-8*width, 270, 320+x-8*width, 270, 320+x-8*width, 216);

  //Kuwait flag, 10
  fill(80, 168, 62); //green quad
  quad(0+x-9*width, 0, 80+x-9*width, 90, 320+x-9*width, 90, 320+x-9*width, 0);
  fill(250); //white quad
  quad(80+x-9*width, 90, 80+x-9*width, 180, 320+x-9*width, 180, 320+x-9*width, 90);
  fill(250, 0, 0); //red quad
  quad(80+x-9*width, 180, 0+x-9*width, 270, 320+x-9*width, 270, 320+x-9*width, 180);
  fill(0); //black quad
  quad(0+x-9*width, 0, 0+x-9*width, 270, 80+x-9*width, 180, 80+x-9*width, 90);

  x=x+1; //scrolls flags to right

  if (x==9*width) { //resets flag scrolling, the number multiplied 
    x=0; //to the width is how many flag widths the first flag has moved
  }   // so the end result will be 9 widths bc we have 10 flags
}
```

Comment: I see `void`, so I would say `Java`. More precisely, [Processing language](http://processing.org/).

Comment: The questioner said Processing, so that would be Java, not JavaScript.

Comment: Processing 2.0 is Processing language based on Java and there is JavaScript version and its in [Processing.js](http://processingjs.org/)

Answer (score 0):

In Processing, the `background()` method overwrites everything that has already been drawn with the background color.  However, you seem to have already drawn some things before you call it.  Try using `fill()` to set the color and then `quad()` to draw the background for that flag only.

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the line color with stroke(color) before drawing a line, then set the stroke off using noStroke()

Answer (score 0):

Because you are drawing one big wall of flags and move this wall before canvas (camera) you can't change background just for this small moving section it will affect whole wall of flags. So why you just don't use your procedure of overlapping rectangles as all time so your Jamaica flag will be ok.

```
//jamaica, flag 8
fill(250,230, 82); // yellow background
rect(0+x-7*width,0,width, width);
fill (0, 250, 0); //green triangle top
triangle (10+x-7*width, 0, 160+x-7*width, 120, 310+x-7*width, 0);
fill (0, 250, 0); //green triangle bot
triangle (10+x-7*width, 270, 160+x-7*width, 150, 310+x-7*width, 270);
fill (0); //black triangle left
triangle (0+x-7*width, 10, 145+x-7*width, 135, 0+x-7*width, 260);
fill (0); //black triangle right
triangle (320+x-7*width, 10, 175+x-7*width, 135, 320+x-7*width, 260);
```

btw for height parameter it is better to use `height` instead of `width` all time.

Answer (score 0):

its old post but this might help

```
Image img = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().createImage("JamaicaFlag.jpeg");
```

---

this page should give you more info

[***Toolkit.createImage***](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Toolkit.html#createImage(java.lang.String))